# Capturing Metadata off Music CD during file transfer

Tags: music, cd, metadata, flac

When I transfer.wav files off a music CD to my /Music folder on my hard drive the metadata (song/artist information) is not present. I can look at the music CD with, say, Rhythmbox and see the song/artist information but I believe it is sourcing this data off the web and not the CD. Is there a way to capture this information off the CD itself or do I know if it is even present? Looking at the 'properties' of the individual CD music files shows nothing under the 'General' information. Also the songs on the CD are simply listed as Track 1.wav, etc; no song titles. This all means that I have to manually rename these songs on my hard drive and my USB memory stick that I use on my stereo network receiver. I am using FLAC, in Terminal mode, to convert the .wav files for more efficient storage.This is also cumbersome but I want to ensure music quality/sampling rate is maintained for playback on my stereo.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Asunder seems to fit my needs. With Asunder it is fairly quick and easy to add some of the basic metadata including album, artist, track number, genre and year, but some other metadata information is not supported in the Asunder interface.

Comment: @EdDelauter I recommend expanding this to explain *how* you used Asunder to achieve this, so that others in similar situations will benefit more.